# Spring test rest api

Tags: spring, junit, jacoco

We have a three maven modules

First Project consists of all Rest API.

Second contains Business classes

Third contains DAL classes.

I have written test cases only in my rest api layer. I have configured jacoco plugin to create code coverage report. It works fine. But my problem is the code coverage report only gets created for rest api layer. How can i create code coverage report for all the layers even though the test cases are only written in rest api module . Is this something possible?

```
Parent
  ------REST(Test cases are only return for rest api methods)
  ------Business
  ------DAL
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to add **jacoco plugin configuration in parent pom**.

For a multi-module project like yours, try looking at this [example](https://dzone.com/articles/jacoco-maven-multi-module).
Hope this would help.

EDIT:
 As per the suggestion from [Godin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244993/godin), we can use `report-aggregate` goal to generate the report in multi-module. 

 [Link to documentation](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html)

Comment: In case of aggregation of coverage from multiple modules there is `report-aggregate` ( http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html ), which is not necessarily declared in parent pom.

Comment: @Godin Thanks for that :) added EDIT to my answer

Comment: Does this help even if there are no test cases for other modules?